# ASP.NET Limit number download

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to limit the number of downloads like the site Rapidshare or Megaupload does using asp.net

Answer (score 1):

one option: track the IP address

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore_members.aspx) to prevent it.  It would be something like the following:

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0, 5, "<Client IP Address, or Session/Auth Cookie>");
if( !sem.WaitOne(0) ) 
    throw new Exception();

try {
    ... write download ...
}
finally { sem.Release(); }
```